# how to spy on method inside custom event leaflet

Tags: jquery, jasmine, leaflet, angular7

I need to test for a third party function (map.setZoom) was called with a specific param (in this case, 18)

```
createMap() {
    const map = this.variable;
    map.locate({setView: true, enableHighAccuracy: true});
    map.on('locationfound', (e) => {
        map.setZoom(18);
    });
  }
```

My spec looks like this:

```
let component: Component;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            // declarations, imports, etc..
        }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('should verify map was created with zoom 18', () => {
        spyOn(component.variable, 'setZoom').and.callThrough();
        component.createMap();
        $(component.variable).trigger('on');
        expect(component.variable.setZoom).toHaveBeenCalledWith(18);
});
```

but I got this:
[image]

The problem is that the function I want to test is inside a jquery-triggered custom event and I don't know If I'm triggering it right

Comment: You need to trigger `locationfound`, not `on`.  You trigger the event name.

Comment: I've just tried and it throws me the spy was never called.

Comment: Is `component.variable` already a jQuery object?  I ask because the `createMap()` is calling `on()` without wrapping it.  But your logic is trying to wrap the variable before calling trigger.  There may be something there with trying to wrap an already wrapped element.  Try changing `$(component.variable).trigger('locationfound')` to just `component.variable.trigger('locationfound')`

Comment: That might be. Frontend just told `on()` method actually is from a jquery-based leaflet method (or something like that) but not the jquery `on()`. I'm gonna looking for it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Taplar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586174/taplar) suggested, I needed to trigger using `'locationfound'` not `'on'`. Also, talking to the frontend guy I realised that the `on()` method in this case actually is from leaflet not from jquery. Leaflet triggers events using [`fire()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#evented-fire) method. Thus, the final spec is:

```
it('should verify map was created with zoom 18', () => {
        spyOn(component.variable, 'setZoom').and.callThrough();
        component.createMap();
        component.variable.fire('locationfound');
        expect(component.variable.setZoom).toHaveBeenCalledWith(18);
});
```